# How to add multiple student data dynamically using ArrayList ?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

I want to add multiple student data dynamically by using ArrayList but it shows wrong print
 e.g

STD.Student@1a2760f
 STD.Student@f4d6b3

```
public class Student {
            String strName;
            int iRollNum;


    public static void main(String[] args) {        



    ArrayList<Student> myArrayList=new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student student=new Student("Asha",4);
        myArrayList.add(student);
        Student student2=new Student("Asha",4);
        Student student3=new Student("Asha",4);
        Student student4=new Student("Asha",4);
        Student student5=new Student("Asha",4);
        myArrayList.add(student2);
        myArrayList.add(student3);
        myArrayList.add(student4);
        myArrayList.add(student5);

        for (int i = 0; i <myArrayList.size(); i++) {   


    System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i));
            }


            }

                public Student(String strName, int iRollNum) {
                this.strName = strName;
                this.iRollNum = iRollNum;
            }
```

plz help how to slove this problem

Comment: The problem is not related to ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "("+strName+", "+iRollNum+")";
}
```

Add this method to Student. println uses toString to determine how to display the string. By default, it only displays the class name and a random-ish number.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're getting the `toString()` method from `java.lang.Object` - which includes Class and Reference Address. It sounds like **you want to override (and you can override)** the `toString()` method in Student with something like this

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.valueOf(iRollNum) + " " + strName;
}
```

Comment: You should have mentioned that it's actually possible to override `toString()` method.

Comment: @diegoaguilar I added the (completely optional) `@Override` annotation.

Comment: I meant, tell the asker that is possible to override the method ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) { 
    System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i));
}
```

Use regular for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) { 
    System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i).iRollNum+" - "+myArrayList.get(i).strName);
}
```

OR advanced for loop:

```
for (Student student: myArrayList) { 
    System.out.println(student.iRollNum+" - "+student.strName);
}
```

This will print output like:

4 - Asha

4 - Asha

4 - Asha

4 - Asha

4 - Asha

You need to point to that specific object in ArrayList of type student using:

```
myArrayList.get(i)
```

and then to print the objects variable you need to use

```
.iRollNum or .strName
```

In advance for loop you create a object Student student and so you can use that object to refer to object's variable/functions directly

You can also use @Paperwaste 's method of overriding toString method - elegant way of doing same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`myArrayList.get(1)` returns a student object. When trying to print this it is calling the default toString() method. you need to include a toString method. Try adding this method to your student class

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.strName + " " + this.iRollNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code :

```
for (int i = 0; i <myArrayList.size(); i++) {   
       System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i));
}
```

with this :

```
for (Student student : myArrayList ){
 System.Out.Println(student.toString());
}
```

or if you dont have the toString method you can use student.get<> method to get the value you want

Answer (score 0):

What I have another parameter of class Student as marks, which is an array-like:

```
int[] marks = new int[]{90, 80, 99, 95};
```

In this case what we need to do with the `toString()` method to print the array result.